# how to fetch phone_no from cognito api response

Tags: python

calling cognito `admingetuser`

`response = client.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId='string',
    Username='string'
)`

In response i getting back `response` as

`response {'Username': 'xyz@gmail.com', 
'UserAttributes': [{'Name': 'sub', 'Value': 'cb0328a8-38fd-4799-84ef-4f7f2733016e'}, {'Name': 'email_verified', 'Value': 'true'}, 
{'Name': 'phone_number_verified', 'Value': 'false'}, {'Name': 'phone_number', 'Value': '+445115115551'}, 
{'Name': 'custom:account_id', 'Value': 'a54a936f-d846-44ec-8f6f-c9e127991bda'}, 
{'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'xyz@gmail.com'}], 'UserCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 10, 13, 46, 47, 533000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 
'UserLastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 14, 16, 24, 20, 707000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Enabled': True, 'UserStatus': 'CONFIRMED', 
'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '5c649fd3-1005-11e9-b484-433d044b60ba', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fri, 04 Jan 2019 09:44:42 GMT', 
'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 
'content-length': '500', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '5c649fd3-1005-11e9-b484-433d044b60ba'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}"`

i want extract phone_no from this response in python how i can do that?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the json loaded as dict (one way or another):

```
def get_phone(response):
    for user_attribute in response.get('UserAttributes', []):
        if user_attribute['Name'] == 'phone_number':
            yield user_attribute['Value']

response = {'Username': 'xyz@gmail.com', 
'UserAttributes': [{'Name': 'sub', 'Value': 'cb0328a8-38fd-4799-84ef-4f7f2733016e'}, {'Name': 'email_verified', 'Value': 'true'}, 
{'Name': 'phone_number_verified', 'Value': 'false'}, {'Name': 'phone_number', 'Value': '+440123456789'}, 
{'Name': 'custom:account_id', 'Value': 'a54a936f-d846-44ec-8f6f-c9e127991bda'}, 
{'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'xyz@gmail.com'}]...}

print(list(get_phone(response)))
```

`get_phone` is generator function, so it will handle possible multiple phone numbers (if present?) and you can iterate over the result one number at a time instead of converting to list.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cognito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) response is in JSON format.

So you could simply parse response as a json using `json.loads(response)`. This way you will probably get list of dictionaries. One of this list elements will be dictionary contain `phone_number`. Value under `Value` key in that dictionary is a phone number.

Comment: It's actually already a `dict`: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_get_user